# yeoman - SASS and Bower clash issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, yeoman, bower, yeoman-generator

I updated yeoman today. I am now using the web app generator.

I get this error when running "grunt serve".

"error app/styles/main.scss (Line 121 of app/bower_components/sass-bootstrap/lib/_mixins.scss: Invalid CSS after "...-shadow($shadow": expected ")", was "...) {")"

I cannot solve this at all have uninstalled everything and re-installed to latest version.

I had other problems before this but this is the only one I cannot resolve.

Please help.

Comment: can you add to this post the contents of your main.scss file? And check version of you sass: sass -v

Comment: Sass 3.2.12 (Media Mark) is the version

Comment: $icon-font-path: "/bower_components/sass-bootstrap/fonts/";

@import 'sass-bootstrap/lib/bootstrap';

This is the content of main.scss